# Pass values between 2 elements triggered by jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a problem with a javascript. I am a beginner in javascript. I am trying to push data to textarea from h1 tag. Actually, I  have a product website build using woocommerce. When visitor click some product, I open a chat box with Product title.   Currently, I have tested pass with some custom value to that textarea. Now I need to pass it to customer clicked product title. This is my script. I need to replace "This is my custom value" with visitor clicked product title.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // alert( "ready!" );
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".btn-test", function (e) {
    // Check if valid email or name is available
    if (!wplc_cookie_email || !wplc_cookie_name) {
      console.log("Test");
      alert('Please log in to the chat to proceed');
    } else {
      // Open the chat if closed
      if (!$('#wp-live-chat-header').hasClass('active')) {
        document.getElementById("wp-live-chat-header").click();
      }
      // Pass text to the chat input - text area
      $("textarea#wplc_chatmsg").val("This is my custom value");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You want to get the value of `.btn-test` and put on textarea?

Comment: From where your product title shows?

Comment: @SumeshTG  Yes. It's Add to cart button. I need get the product title. I have that title like this <h1 class="product_title entry-title">Item 01</h1>. Can I get this title value to the textarea value, using class name? is It possible. Or how i can do it?

Comment: You can access an element by classname with `$(".product_title")` but you shouldn't, it is much safer to use an unique id in order to avoid grabbing the wrong element

Comment: @StefanBlamberg How can I pass it to my textarea ?

Comment: @Sanjaya Try `$("textarea#wplc_chatmsg").val($('.product_title entry-title').text());` or `$("textarea#wplc_chatmsg").val($('.product_title entry-title').html());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the title with jquery like this `$("#idOfYourH1").html();` and pass it to the `val()` function. However I wouldn't recommend it, you should use the original string from the product information which is probably accessible somewhere directly in the code instead.

Edit:
Try changing the value with `$("textarea#wplc_chatmsg").val($(".product_title.entry-title").html());`

Comment: It's not possible. That title is dynamic value. Hence, I only can catch it through class name. This is my h1 tag. "<h1 class="product_title entry-title">Item 01</h1>". Can you help me to resolve this?

Comment: It's Work. You are awesome. I have edit it like this. $("textarea#wplc_chatmsg").val($(".product_title.entry-title").html()+$(".product_price").html()); Is there any way to add line break to set next line go to product price?

Comment: You can simply append `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, suppose this is your product,

```
<div class="product" data-title="product_title">
.......
.....
</div>
```

now you can get data-title with jquery.data as in jquery documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)
like

```
 $(".product").on("click",function(){
    var title=$(this).data("title");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use .text() to remove html from title before putting it in the textarea..

```
$("textarea#wplc_chatmsg").val($(".product_title.entry-title").text()
+ "\n" + $(".product_price").text());
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to get href value also?

Comment: Yes, you can use the common `var myHref = $(".mylink").attr("href");` to get te href of an anchor